# In Fedora + KDE Plasma Firefox sometimes ignores change of keyboard layout

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, firefox

I'm using Fedora 35. It was the main version (Gnome), but then I installed KDE pleasma using `sudo dnf install @kde-desktop`. I have two keyboards **English** and **Persian**.

Sometimes Firefox ignores the keyboard layout and types English anyway. Other programs seem to be fine. A restart fixes this temporarily until the next time that it happens.

What can be done about this?

System info:

```
Fedora 35
KDE Plasma Version: 5.23.3
KDE Framework Version: 5.88.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.15.6.200.fc35.x86_64 (64-bit)
Graphic Platform: Wayland
Firefox: 94.0
```

The laptop is a framework Laptop.

**UPDATE:**
At least one othe application is affected: vscode. at the same time, some other applicaitions are not affected, like LbreOffice Writer and Telegram Desktop.

The affected applications have another strange bahaviour: `Ctrl+.` types a single `e` chracter with an underline, that cannot be deleted by backspace, but typing `ctrl+.` again removes it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be IBus, enabled by default in Gnome.

I needed to use "input method selector" and switch from "Use IBus (recommended)" to "No Input Method"

After logout, things will be normal

Comment: Could you elaborate, where do you change from IBUS to "No Input Method"?

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not include enough information. Unfortunately, that system is now formatted with a clean Fedora+KDE installation that does not have that problem. Ironically, I always get frustrated by vague answers like this, and now I know how people come up with those.

Comment: Anyway, from a search, it might appear in: System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Layouts

Comment: I run in a similar issue. For some reason, I cannot change the keyboard layout while Switching Policy from Keyboard -> Layout is set to Application. Switching to anything else restores change layout functionality.